# Autocomplete in some python's module in VIM

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, jedi, youcompleteme

I use VIM on last Fedora with jedi-vim. It works perfect, but some module jedi can't autocomplite.
For exemple I use `pyautogui` module. With this module autocomplite don't works. And I have seen several similar modules.
I tested this module in Sublime Text with jedi and andconda plugin, and they can't autocomplite this file too. ( But PyCharm work's fine with it).

I can't understand why? Jedi can't autocomplite big and complicated modules? Or some modules have structure's problem? Are there any solutions to problem with autocomplite?
Maybe vim have some other plugin for good autocomplite for Python 3? ( i read YouComplite don't work with third version )

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? And is Vim using the correct one?

Comment: No i use default system Python 3.4. With Python evn i haven't any problem.